# Pressure in a bottle

Tags: pressure

I am fermenting this tea by putting it is an airtight bottle and adding some sugar which will produce CO2. Will there be more carbonation in the final product if I fill the bottle 99% full with tea vs 90% full. Is the difference proportionate to the amount of tea in the bottle ? In other words, is the amount on CO2 in any volume of the bottle going to be the same regardless whether it is filled with tea or with air ?

Comment: Might [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) or [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (aka cooking) be better suited for this question?

Comment: Not sure, I'm new here. However the question "is there the same amount of CO2 per volume in a closed system in the water/tea part and the air part" sounds like fundamentally a physics thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have brewed ginger beer and the amount of headspace allows for longer fermentation before the bottle bursts or the process slows down through high pressure [Pascalization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascalization) "a method of preserving and sterilizing food, in which a product is processed under very high pressure, leading to the inactivation of certain microorganisms and enzymes in the food". I get more carbonation through a few more days of cold fermentation in the fridge after two or three days brewing at room temperature.